unexpected `cfg` condition value: `solana`
so im trying to build using anchor on wsl, but everytime it will always gave a warning like this
warning: unexpected `cfg` condition value: `solana`
 --> programs/vote-sc/src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
5 | #[program]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: expected values for `target_os` are: `aix`, `android`, `cuda`, `dragonfly`, `emscripten`, `espidf`, `freebsd`, `fuchsia`, `haiku`, `hermit`, `horizon`, `hurd`, `illumos`, `ios`, `l4re`, `linux`, `macos`, `netbsd`, `none`, `nto`, `nuttx`, `openbsd`, `psp`, `psx`, `redox`, `rtems`, `solaris`, `solid_asp3`, `teeos`, `trusty`, `tvos`, `uefi`, `unknown`, `visionos`, and `vita` and 6 more
  = note: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/check-cfg/cargo-specifics.html> for more information about checking conditional configuration
  = note: this warning originates in the macro `$crate::custom_panic_default` which comes from the expansion of the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

ive tried to reinstall everything but it seems didnt solve any problem.
I also have another warning but it seems I can fix it by adding
anchor-debug = []
custom-heap = []
custom-panic = []

...to [features] in my Cargo.toml , then it would only leave the target_os warning

This issue is currently caused by Rust nightly versions >= 2024-11-20, and at least affects Anchor v0.30.1. Anchor makes use of Rust nightly for some features like IDL generation.
The nightly version I've found to work without warning is nightly-2024-11-19.
Try:
RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN="nightly-2024-11-19" anchor build


Thanks @david I had the same issue and can confirm that removed the warnings for me. I also didn't need to add any features to Cargo.toml.

Since "solana" is not a recognized OS in the base Rust toolchain, it complains about a bad configuration. If you want to silence the warning, you can add the following to a workspace Cargo.toml:
[workspace.lints.rust.unexpected_cfgs]
level = "warn"
check-cfg = [
    'cfg(target_os, values("solana"))',
]

Or a package Cargo.toml:
[package.lints.rust.unexpected_cfgs]
level = "warn"
check-cfg = [
    'cfg(target_os, values("solana"))',
]

